# RichTextEdit with multicolored text?

Tags: blackberry, fonts, colors, rim-4.5, blackberry-os-v4.5

How do I create a `RichTextEdit` using RIM 4.5 API that contains text with multiple colors? 
For example I want to create a `RichTextEdit` as follows:

- The Text is **"Hello BB world"**
- **"Hello"** should be **blue**
- **"BB world"** should be **red**
- **"BB"** should be `ITALIC`
- **"Hello"** should be `BOLD`

The main problem is getting colors, not the bold and italic. 
I have tried overriding `RichTextEdit.paint` function, but this formats the color of the whole string, not just a substring of it!

Here's the code I implemented to make the text bold and italic and overriding the paint to change the whole string color:

```
public final class RichTextFieldSample extends UiApplication 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        RichTextFieldSample theApp = new RichTextFieldSample(); 
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher(); 
    } 
    public RichTextFieldSample() 
    { 
        String richText = "This is how you create text with formatting!!!";
        Font fonts[] = new Font[3]; 
        int[] offset = new int[4]; 
        byte[] attribute = new byte[3]; 
        fonts[0] = Font.getDefault(); 
        fonts[1] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD); 
        fonts[2] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC); 
        offset[0] = 0; 
        attribute[0] = 2; 
        offset[1] = 4; 
        attribute[1] = 0; 
        offset[2] = 33; 
        attribute[2] = 1; 
        offset[3] = richText.length(); 

        RichTextField rtField = new RichTextField 
          (richText, offset, attribute, fonts, 
           RichTextField.USE_TEXT_WIDTH) {
                protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    graphics.clear();
                    graphics.setColor(0x0000FF);
                    super.paint(graphics);
                }
        };

        MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen(); 
        mainScreen.setTitle(new LabelField 
          ("RichTextFieldSample Sample", 
            LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH)); 
        mainScreen.add(rtField); 
        pushScreen(mainScreen); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you post your sample code that sets the font bold and italic?  Also post your code that overrides RichTextEdit.paint.

Comment: Question updated with the sample code you asked for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no easy answer to this one.  According to [this post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/RichTextField-getForegroundColors-what-s-the-point/m-p/195426/highlight/true#M26822), RichTextField doesn't support multiple colors (despite the presence of a `getForegroundColors` method).

It may be possible to extend RichTextField to support multiple colors, but with the amount of work necessary, it would very likely be easier to implement your own `Field` from scratch.